# SQL Server 2008 IsNumeric returns 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a query using `ISNUMERIC` but one of the my data record return it as a numeric.
Is there any way that the query return 0 on this data without removing character function?

```
Declare @Temp Table(Data VarChar(18))

Insert Into @Temp Values('750419.')
Insert Into @Temp Values('7.4')

Select Data,
       IsNumeric(Data) As [IsNumeric],
From   @Temp
```

and also I've found a function named but still wont return it to 0

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[IsInteger](@Value VarChar(18))
Returns Bit
As
Begin
  Return IsNull(
     (Select Case When CharIndex('.', @Value) >= 0
                  Then Case When Convert(int, ParseName(@Value, 1)) <> 0
                            Then 0
                            Else 1
                            End
                  Else 1
                  End
      Where IsNumeric(@Value + 'e0') = 1), 0)
End
```

Comment: Is that SQL Server 2008? I would say that both values are numeric. They are not integers, but they are absolutely numeric. That's because numeric does not mean *contains only numbers*.

Comment: yes.. but i was trying to bypass the .  on the data... is there any posible way?..in the function isinteger.. it bypass the . on the 7.4 data..

Comment: The question is not given specific info. Hence unclear. What is the error???

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Declare @Temp Table(Data VarChar(18))

Insert Into @Temp Values('750419.')
Insert Into @Temp Values('7.4')

Select Data,
       CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(Data) = 0     THEN 0
        WHEN Data LIKE '%[^-+ 0-9.]%' THEN 0
        WHEN CAST(Data AS NUMERIC(38, 0))=cast(Data AS NUMERIC(38, 10)) then 1

        ELSE 0
      END

       [IsNumeric]
From   @Temp
```